# Draw lines by 3d Cursor location and rotation

Tags: python, gpu-module

I want to draw lines using 3d cursor location and rotation (to draw it axis).
How to calculate endpoint location for each axis?

Example:

[image]

```
import bpy
import gpu
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader
import bgl

class DrawingClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(self.draw_text_callback, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_VIEW')

    def draw_text_callback(self):
        center = bpy.context.scene.cursor.location
        co = center.to_tuple()

        position = [co, (co[0]+1.0, co[1], co[2]),
                    co, (co[0], co[1]+1.0, co[2]),
                    co, (co[0], co[1], co[2]+1.0)]
                    
        shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin('3D_SMOOTH_COLOR')
        
        col = [(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
               (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0),
               (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0), (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)]
               
        batch = batch_for_shader(shader, 'LINES', {"pos": position, "color": col})

        bgl.glLineWidth(3)
        shader.bind()
        batch.draw(shader)

    def remove_handle(self):
        bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self.handle, 'WINDOW')

# to draw
context = bpy.context             
dns = bpy.app.driver_namespace
dns["dc"] = DrawingClass()

# to remove
dns = bpy.app.driver_namespace
dc = dns.get("dc")
dc.remove_handle()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
import bpy
import gpu
from mathutils import Vector
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader

indices = ((0, 1),)
cursor3d = bpy.context.scene.cursor
center = cursor3d.location
for e in dir(cursor3d):print(e)

mat = cursor3d.matrix

x_coords = (center, mat @ Vector((1, 0, 0)))
y_coords = (center, mat @ Vector((0, 1, 0)))
z_coords = (center, mat @ Vector((0, 0, 1)))

shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin('3D_UNIFORM_COLOR')
batch_x = batch_for_shader(shader, 'LINES', {"pos": x_coords}, indices=indices)
batch_y = batch_for_shader(shader, 'LINES', {"pos": y_coords}, indices=indices)
batch_z = batch_for_shader(shader, 'LINES', {"pos": z_coords}, indices=indices)

def draw():
    shader.bind()
    shader.uniform_float("color", (1, 0, 0, 1))
    batch_x.draw(shader)

    shader.bind()
    shader.uniform_float("color", (0, 1, 0, 1))
    batch_y.draw(shader)

    shader.bind()
    shader.uniform_float("color", (0, 0, 1, 1))
    batch_z.draw(shader)

bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_VIEW')
```

Comment: Thank you! I used matrix.to3x3 and `Vector((co[0]+1.0, co[1], co[2]))` and couldn't figure out what was wrong.

Comment: The 3D cursor has a rotation and you're ignoring it. If +1 just moves right from world space.

Comment: 3.5.0+ API changes https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender-manual/issues/103176